# What is the difference in clearing the exponent?

Tags: logarithms

If I have an equation, like this:

$k^{m} = m^{k}$,

I have been taught that I must apply natural logarithm, but others have taught me that I must apply the common logarithm.

Then, what should I use?

$m*ln(k)= k*ln(m)$, Natural logarithm (base $e$)?

$m*log(k)= k*log(m)$, Common logarithm (base $10$)?

I guess, the only difference is that:

Natural logarithm will leave the answer in terms of $e$ and common logarithm, will leave the answer in terms of $10$, but I'm not sure about this and I need a really good explanation, when it's convenient to use one and the other.

Comment: Always natural logarithm. Always.

Comment: $\ln$ is more popular than $\log$

Comment: Why ? @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: Common and natural logs are proportional, so either will serve to answer the question. The natural logarithm is, well, natural (for mathematicians), It's the most useful in abstract mathematics. Base $10$ logarithms are a historical accident, coming from the fact that we have $10$ fingers, so base $10$ notation for integers. The common logarithm was invented to speed calculation. The only other logarithm you encounter these days is base $2$, useful in computer science.

Comment: Use whatever logarithm you like.  If you use base $k$ you get $m = k\log_k m$ and if you use base $m$ you get $k = m\log_m k$. But all $m \log_b k = k\log_b m$ will all be true statements, so whichever helps you solve will work.  (Although frustratingly none really help much.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$k^m = m^k \implies m\log_b k = k\log_a m$ will be true no matter what base $b$ you choose.  And as $\log_b k$ an $\log_b m$ will always be in the same proportion ($\frac {\log_b k}{\log_b m} = \frac {\log_a k}{\log_a m}$ for all legitimate $a,b$) it doesn't matter which you pick.

Unless you are doing scientific notation where units and measurements are specifically designed to be represented in powers of $10$s there is *nothing* advantageous about $10$ over, say, $17$.  And $k \log_{17} m = m\log_{17}k$ is a perfectly true and legitimate statement.

But if you *are* doing scientific notation where units are based on powers of $10$ then $\log_{10}$ has an *obvious* advantage.

If you are doing anything that might even remotely no matter how obliquely involve differentiation or integration (or even tangents or rates of change) you should use $\ln$ as it is ... natural.  So that is why it is conventional to default to natural logs.

I'm surprised though that no-one has suggested logs based $k$ or $m$.  That has the advantage of reducing an equation with two logarithms to one.  $m = k\log_k m$ and $k = m\log_m k$ which could often help us.  Although in this case it doesn't)

Use whatever base you like.  Sometimes there will be practical advantages to use a specific base  (Solve for $3^{27x} = y^{81} \cdot 3^{7}$ just screams for base $3$) but usually there won't be.  The convention is math is base $e$.  I imagine im must sciences is is also base $e$ but I imagine there are same instances where convention is $10$.

But it doesn't matter.

===

$3^{27x} = y^{81} \cdot 3^{7}$

$\log_3 3^{27x} = \log_3(y^{81} \cdot 3^{7})$

$27x = 81\log_3 y + 7$

$x = 3\log_3 y + \frac 7{27}$.

But you could just as well (but not as easily solve it with natural logs.

$\ln 3^{27x} = \ln(y^{81} \cdot 3^{7})$

$27x \ln 3 = 81\ln y + 7\ln 3$.

$x = \frac {81\ln y + 7\ln 3}{27\ln 3}$

$= 3\frac {\ln y}{\ln 3} + \frac 7{27}$.  The same answer.

And if we had use common $\log$ wed have gotten.

$x = 3\frac {\log y}{\log 3} + \frac 7{27}$.

All the same.

Comment: thanks, good answer

Answer (score 0):

$$k^m=m^k\to m\log_a(k)=k\log_a(m)\to\frac1k\log_a(k)=\frac1m\log_a(m)\space\forall a\in \Bbb R^+$$

The most popular choice for $a$ is Euler's Constant $e$, for which we use the notation $\log_e(x)=\ln(x)$

Hence:
$$\frac 1k\ln(k)=\frac 1m\ln (m)$$